# Data protection issue with other editors except owner in Google App Scripts having onEdit() trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheets with 6 editors including me as a owner. When any editor except the owner of the sheets selects certain value in the dropdown menu, the onEdit trigger attached with classAttendance() starts working. That's fine. But the issue is, every time the data is protected on the owner name (has edit access) though the user is different editor. It should be on that specific editor name and should have edit access to it. How to solve it?

```
function classAttendance(e){ 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A4").getValue();    
  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 1-Period") {  
      refreshSheet();
      onePeriod();    
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 2-Period") {    
      refreshSheet();
      twoPeriod();
  }    
}

function refreshSheet() {   
  //For protecting dashboard while scripts running
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
   
  var rangem = dashboard.getRange("A1:K71");
  
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var description = 'Scripts running on ' + stringDate + ' by ' + me;
  
  var protectionm = rangem.protect().setDescription(description);  
  protectionm.addEditor(me);
  protectionm.removeEditors(protectionm.getEditors());
  if (protectionm.canDomainEdit()) {
      protectionm.setDomainEdit(false);
  }  
 
 Utilities.sleep(300000);     
 
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but I can't quite understand the issue here: `"But the issue is, every time the data is protected on the owner name (has edit access) though the user is different editor. It should be on that specific editor name and should have edit access to it."`. Can you please make a few examples of this behavior in your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) for installable triggers:

> The installable version runs with the authorization of the user who created the trigger, even if another user with edit access opens the spreadsheet.

Now, the documentaiton for [removeEditor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditoremailaddress) says:

> Neither the owner of the spreadsheet nor the current user can be removed.

In other words:

- Your code removes all editors minus the trigger owner *you) and the spreadsheet owner (probably also you)
- The statement `protectionm.addEditor(me);` will only add you as an editor (but you are already an editor anyway).
- Also, it does not make sense to use `addEditor` before `removeEditos()` - the latter will remove all editors that have been added before.

### Solution:

- Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `user` to retrieve the active user
- Add this user as an editor after removing all the other users (remember that you as the spreadsheet owner cannot be removed from the editors)

**Sample for implementation:**

```js
function classAttendance(e){
//////////MODIFICATION HERE
  var user = e.user; 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A4").getValue();    
  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 1-Period") {  
//////////MODIFICATION HERE
      refreshSheet(user);
      onePeriod();    
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 2-Period") {  
//////////MODIFICATION HERE  
      refreshSheet(user);
      twoPeriod();
  }    
}
//////////MODIFICATION HERE
function refreshSheet(user) {   
  //For protecting dashboard while scripts running
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
   
  var rangem = dashboard.getRange("A1:K71");
  
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var description = 'Scripts running on ' + stringDate + ' by ' + me;
  
  var protectionm = rangem.protect().setDescription(description);  
  protectionm.removeEditors(protectionm.getEditors());
//////////MODIFICATION HERE
  protectionm.addEditor(user);
  if (protectionm.canDomainEdit()) {
      protectionm.setDomainEdit(false);
  }   
 Utilities.sleep(300000);      
}
```

Comment: hi, I am facing a difficult issue at my project and could you please assist at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549880/how-to-insert-the-email-address-by-querying-corresponding-id-using-google-app-sc