# How to insert the email address by querying corresponding ID using Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In case of my current codes for doing MANUAL ENTRY, when I select a subject, a date and input maximum 4 student IDs at a time (e.g. 1802001, 1802002, 1802004 for example) and then select an option, it just concatenate with the email pattern (e.g @icte.bdu.ac.bd) and insert those to the destination subject sheet selected earlier.

I do not want to use the Email Pattern (@icte.bdu.ac.bd) any more. My current codes work fine given that all email addresses of a batch of students are similar (e.g. 1902001@ubd.ac.bd, 1902002@ubd.ac.bd). However, at many institutions does not provide email addresses based on student ID number, often it is like tom@ubd.ac.bd or james@ubd.ac.bd.

Please note that student IDs are same when do inputs to the Dashboard (see attached image) and also in the StudentList sheet but it differs in the destination sheet (HUM4105) such as 1802001, 1802003, "Roll No.:18.02.004
Reg No.:2018.11.000027". However, email address of students are same at all places and it should be used as a basis.Actually it is a student attendance system where the inputs usually come from an android app. If few students miss to report attendance, then we do manual entry.

> What I am trying to do is, when I will input the student IDs, maximum 4 at time (e.g.
> 1802001, 1802003) it will actually insert their corresponding email
> address from a Google sheet (StudentList) to the subject sheet selected earlier (HUM4105). The StudentList
> sheet contains SID in COLUMN D and Email in Column F. Please note that Edit trigger is already there and when a certain option is selected, the following code is executed.

The codes are:

```
function manualEntry(e){ 
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
      var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("F5").getValue(); 
      var mDate = dashboard.getRange("G5").getDisplayValue();
      var sheetw = dashboard.getRange("A8");
      var sheetw2 = dashboard.getRange("G8");
           
        if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'K6' && e.range.getValue() === "Report 1P") {
          sheetw2.setValue('Manual entry process is up and running. Please Wait!').setFontColor('Red');
          onePeriodm();       
          sheetw.setValue('You may take class attendance now. Thank You!').setFontColor('Green');
          sheetw2.setValue('You may do manual entry now. Thank You!').setFontColor('Green');
        }
   }          
    
    function onePeriodm(){
    //for one period manual entry
      const srcSheetName = "Dashboard";
    
      // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
      const [
        [, , , , , emailPattern],
        ,
        [courseCatalogId, dateString, ...studentIds],
      ] = srcSheet.getRange("F3:K5").getDisplayValues();
    
      // 2. Retrieve current values
      const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(courseCatalogId);
      const dstCurrentValues = dstSheet
        .getRange(`A2:C${dstSheet.getLastRow()}`) // expanded to include email column
        .getDisplayValues(); // not flattening since we have multiple columns now
    
      // 3. Convert the values for putting to the destination sheet.
      //    Do not include if there is already an email for this date in current values
      const dstValues = studentIds.reduce((array, studentId) => {
        const existingEntry = dstCurrentValues.find(
          (row) => row[0] === dateString && row[2] === studentId + emailPattern
        );
        if (studentId != "" && !existingEntry)
          array.push([
            dateString,
            Number(studentId),
            studentId + emailPattern,
            ,
            ,
            courseCatalogId,
          ]);
        return array;
      }, []);
    
      // 4. Put the converted values to the destination sheet.
      const index = dstCurrentValues.map((row) => row[0]).lastIndexOf(dateString);
      const row = index + 2;
      if (dstValues.length > 0){
         dstSheet.insertRowsAfter(row, dstValues.length);
         dstSheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code is combining the id with the email pattern. So for the code to work in both cases you'll need to have a check in place to identify when to concatenate the ID with the email pattern and when to substitute the ID with the whole email address. (I am assuming the whole email address is in the StudentList sheet in column F.)

If the whole email is always listed, even when it is  based on the student ID, I would do away with the concatenation of the ID and email pattern entirely and just use the substitution of ID with whole email address.

Here are the steps that need to be implemented in your code:

1. Get the range from StudentList columns D through F. This will be an
   array (say studentListArray).
2. Get the array of student IDs. (If you structured your dashboard differently, you could simply list as many ID's as you want in the row instead of doing just 4 at a time.)
3. Check your array of ID's for duplicates.
4. Loop through the ID array and filter the studentListArray by ID on studentListArray[0] returning studentListArray[2].
5. Check filter result is not undefined.
6. If filter result is not undefined, set result as student email.

**EDIT**

---

Here is the example sheet with changes to the code:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/146vRZ1QDGpnzhxnAuQ03qX4jTORZdj_piueW7ORfYDY/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code for `onePeriodm()`:

```
function onePeriodm(){
  //For protecting dashboard while scripts running
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  
  //### new code ##########################################
  var studentListSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("StudentList");
  var studentList = studentListSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var studentEmail = null;
  var tempEmail = null;
  //### end new code ######################################
  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");  
  var sheetw = dashboard.getRange("A8");
  var sheetw2 = dashboard.getRange("G8");  
  sheetw.setValue('Class Attendance is restricted now. Try Again Later!').setFontColor('Red');
   
  var rangem = dashboard.getRange("A4:K6");
  
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm');
  //var me2 = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var me2 = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var description = 'Scripts running on ' + stringDate + ' by ' + me2;
  
  //var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  //var description = 'Scripts are running by ' + me;
  var protectionm = rangem.protect().setDescription(description);  
  protectionm.removeEditors(protectionm.getEditors());
  protectionm.addEditor(me2);
  if (protectionm.canDomainEdit()) {
      protectionm.setDomainEdit(false);
  }  
  
  //Refreshing sheet with removing unprotectd data
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");  
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("F5").getValue(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  //For removing unprotected rows of data from a particular sheet  
  // 1. Retrieve data range.
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();

    // 2. Create an object from the protected range. This is used for removing from the cleared rows.
    const protectedRanges = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).map(e => {
      const r = e.getRange();
      const start = r.getRow();
      return {start: start, end: r.getNumRows() + start - 1};
    });

    // 3. Create range list for clearing rows using the object.
    let rangeList = [];
    for (let r = 2; r <= dataRange.getNumRows(); r++) {
      let bk = false;
      for (let e = 0; e < protectedRanges.length; e++) {
        if (protectedRanges[e].start == r) {
          r = protectedRanges[e].end;
          bk = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!bk) rangeList.push(`A${r}:${r}`);
    }

    // 4. Delete the rows without the rows of the protected ranges.
    if (rangeList.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).getRanges().reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
    //sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).getRanges().reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
  

  //for one period manual entry
  const srcSheetName = "Dashboard";

  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const [
    [, , , , , emailPattern],
    ,
    [courseCatalogId, dateString, ...studentIds],
  ] = srcSheet.getRange("F3:K5").getDisplayValues();

  // 2. Retrieve current values
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(courseCatalogId);
  const dstCurrentValues = dstSheet
    .getRange(`A2:C${dstSheet.getLastRow()}`) // expanded to include email column
    .getDisplayValues(); // not flattening since we have multiple columns now

  // 3. Convert the values for putting to the destination sheet.
  //    Do not include if there is already an email for this date in current values
  const dstValues = studentIds.reduce((array, studentId) => {
    const existingEntry = dstCurrentValues.find(
      (row) => row[0] === dateString && +row[1] === +studentId //(row) => row[0] === dateString && row[2] === studentId + emailPattern //############# code change
  );
//### new code ##########################################
tempEmail = studentList.filter(function(a){return (+a[3]) == (+studentId);})[0];
if (tempEmail != undefined && tempEmail != null &&tempEmail != ""){
  studentEmail = tempEmail[5];
}else{
  studentEmail = studentId + emailPattern;
}
//### end new code ######################################

    if (studentId != "" && !existingEntry)
      array.push([
        dateString,
        Number(studentId),
        studentEmail,//studentId + emailPattern //############# code change
        ,
        ,
        courseCatalogId,
      ]);
    return array;
  }, []);

  // 4. Put the converted values to the destination sheet.
  const index = dstCurrentValues.map((row) => row[0]).lastIndexOf(dateString);
  const row = index + 2;
  if (dstValues.length > 0){
     dstSheet.insertRowsAfter(row, dstValues.length);
     dstSheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
  }

  //dstSheet.insertRowsAfter(row, dstValues.length);
  //dstSheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues); 
  protectionm.remove();  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  srcSheet.getRange("F5").setValue("All"); 
  srcSheet.getRange("K6").setValue("Please Select"); 
  srcSheet.getRange("G5:K5").clearContent();
  srcSheet.getRange('G5').clearDataValidations();
  //srcSheet.getRange('G5').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");    
}
```

Comment: please check the attached image.

Comment: can you share a copy of your spreadsheet with fake data in it? there are still too many unknowns to efficiently be of any help. are the full email addresses listed in the StudentList sheet?

Comment: please check this sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bByjpk1XuVDDKr4FYLYt5_oW6ujp7MPqfP7lj_cFjWQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check the manual entry section with Subject HUM4105 and also check the sheet HUM4105 and StudentList tab at the bottom. Please note that subject and sheet name is same here.

Comment: You can check the codes by going to Tools --> Script Editor

Comment: I edited this answer to include the fixed code sample from your above demo sheet. If this works for you, please upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: there are two issues with your code. One is if that any entered student ID does not match with the student ID in the StudentList, it will simply ignore the ID. Second thing is, the Student IDs in the destination sheet is not always like 1802001 or 1802003. It often comes from student ID card Scanning and it look like: "Roll No.:18.02.004
Reg No.:2018.11.000027". So if you want to check whether there is an existing entry of a student ID, you need to check using corresponding email address. I did a little change to your code but did not work

Comment: There will be no email pattern given (e.g. @icte.bdu.ac.bd) and if the student ID entered at Dashboard does not exist at the StudentList, it will simply discard it, therefore, these code may not required:  else{
  studentEmail = studentId + emailPattern;
}

Comment: you may do like this: 1. Take the input from Dashboard and find their corresponding email addresses first from the StudentList. Unlike the destination sheet (e.g. HUM4105), the input at Dashboard and in the StudentList will be always like 1802001, 1802003, etc. Now you have to check whether the student is already there in the destination sheet by using their email address, not student ID as in the destination sheet student ID may like 1802001, or 1802003 or "Roll No.:18.02.004 Reg No.:2018.11.000027". Please consider these suggestions

Answer (score 0):

*Your task can be fulfilled by using an `onEdit` trigger.*

#### Code

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function onEdit(e) {
    let currentSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName();
    let valsToSearchIn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_WHERE_THE_IDS_ARE').getRange(ROW, COL, NO_ROWS, NO_COLS).getValues();

    if (currentSheet == 'SHEET_WHERE_YOU_INPUT_THE_IDS') {
        let inputValue = e.value;
        for (let i = 0; i < valsToSearchIn.length; i++)
            if (valsToSearchIn[i][0] == inputValue) 
                e.range.setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_WHERE_YOU_INPUT_THE_IDS').getRange(i + ROW, COL).getValue());
            else
                SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please input a valid student id!');
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

The above code works by identifying the sheet in which an edit has been by making use of the `e` event object. If the name of this sheet is the same name as `SHEET_WHERE_YOU_INPUT_THE_IDS`, then the value which has been inputted is stored in the `inputValue` variable. Afterwards, it searches in the `valsToSearchIn` array - which is the array in which the student ids are stored, for the `inputValue` and if the search is successful, the corresponding email address will be set in the edited range. If the id is not found, then an alert will be displayed to the user.

#### Note

Please bear in mind that you will have to *adjust* the code above (especially the ranges and the names of the sheets) in order to fit with your requirements.

#### Demo

1. Before the `onEdit(e)` trigger

`SHEET_WHERE_THE_IDS_ARE`

[image: SHEET_WHERE_THE_IDS_ARE before]

`SHEET_WHERE_YOU_INPUT_THE_IDS`

[image: SHEET_WHERE_YOU_INPUT_THE_IDS before]

2. After the `onEdit(e)` trigger

`SHEET_WHERE_YOU_INPUT_THE_IDS`

[image: SHEET_WHERE_YOU_INPUT_THE_IDS after]

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

Comment: my scenario is bit different. The input Google Sheet page is attached to to above post. The edit trigger is already there. What I just need to do is, take one or more input (max four as per input page image) and search the corresponding ID and then insert the corresponding email to the destination sheet.

Comment: What input are you talking about exactly? Would you mind being more precise and offer more details about what exactly are you trying to achieve? Is the script above the `onEdit` trigger?

Comment: please check my complete code at the post. I am taking inputs at Student ID 01 (1802003), Student ID 02 (1802007), Student ID 03 (1802011), etc. Check the attached image as well. These inputs will then search the SID (column 4) of the StudentList sheet. If matches, then it will take the corresponding email address and insert it to the destination sheet. That's All.

Comment: So after executing the `onePeriodm` function triggered by the `manualEntry`, why isn't it possible to add another condition and use the code provided above?

Comment: do I need to create another trigger inside the existing trigger? How many IDs can be inserted at a time? The current codes allow me to insert up to 4 IDs at a time. Please note that the destination sheet is different from where I input IDs, please check the last section of my code at the post.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still find it hard to understand *what* exactly you mean by "it allows me to input 4 ids at a time". Can you also share a sanitized version of the sheet?

Comment: please check the attached image where I can input maximum 4 student IDs. I may enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 IDs. Then I will select the subject (e.g. ICTE4215), a Date and will choose execute option from the drop down menu of Please Select. Execute is an onEdit trigger. Now the IDs will be compared with the column D values of StudentList sheet one by one. Then the corresponding email addresses will be inserted to the last row of a particular date selected earlier to the subject shhet (e.g. ICTE4215). Here sheet name is the subject. That's all.